# Javascript modal window requires scroll down to see

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, popup, modal-dialog

Am currently working with the Soundcloud API to pull images and track links for songs. Am currently showing track info through a modal window upon clicking the album image. However, for the songs on the bottom of the screen, the modal window only appears at the top of the screen, requiring a user to scroll up to see the track info. Probably has something to do with the css positioning but removing position:absolute only puts the modal window at the bottom of all the album images, requiring a scroll down. **How can I make it so that a user's click on an image will open and start the modal window right where they currently are, without scrolling?** Javascript / jquery /css answers all welcomed.

My CSS:

```
#modal { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

#trackinfo {

    width:380px;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #c4e5c1;
    font-family: Rockwell, "Courier Bold", Courier, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;

}

.hidden { 
    display:none;
}
```

My Javascript for show and hide modal:

```
  function doSearch() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search').value;

    // Search soundcloud for artists
    SC.get('/tracks', { q: searchTerm}, function(tracks) {
      for(track in tracks) {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("src", (tracks[track]["artwork_url"]));
        var title = tracks[track].title.replace("'", "\\\'").replace("\"", "\\\"");

        linky = document.createElement('a');
        linky.setAttribute("href", (tracks[track].permalink_url));
        console.log(linky);

        img.setAttribute("onclick", "showTrackInfo('" + title + "\\n"+ tracks[track].uri + " " + "\\n\\n(click to close) " + "')"); 

        console.log(img);


        if (tracks[track]["artwork_url"] == null) {
          console.log(""); } 
        else { 

          var Catalog = document.getElementById('catalog');
          Catalog.appendChild(img);
          $('div#catalog').append('<a href="'+linky+'"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rGdvfl7.png"></a>');

        }
      }
    });
  };

  function showTrackInfo(track) { 
    var trackInfoElement = document.getElementById("trackinfo");
    trackInfoElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(track));

    var modal = document.getElementById("modal"); 
    modal.setAttribute("class", ""); 
  }

  function hidemodal() { 
    var trackInfoElement = document.getElementById("trackinfo");
    trackInfoElement.childNodes;

    while ( trackInfoElement.firstChild ) trackInfoElement.removeChild( trackInfoElement.firstChild );

    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.setAttribute("class", "hidden"); 
  }
```

The functions all work well, I just need to know how to position the modal box upon click so that the user doesn't need to scroll to see the trackinfo. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `position: fixed;` on the dialog box, should make it fill the page no matter where they are on it

Comment: Omg hooray! Such a simple fix! Thank you so much.